# A good approach to different indexes of same resource in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Something I've been wondering about is the best approach to creating a different index view of the same resource in Rails.

For example, let's say you have a group of Users, and the current Index action of the Users Controller that generates a tabular view of the users. You then want to create a second Index view that plotted all the users on a map.  Would the best approach be to create a new action in the Users controller, or to create a new controller (like UsersMap) with a new index?

Thoughts appreciated...

My route file looks like this:

```
resources :users, :only => [:index, :index_with_map, :show, :edit, :update] do 
     match '/index_with_map' => 'users#index_with_map' 
end
```

But hitting "users/index_with_map" results in:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /admin/users/index_with_map Couldn't find User with id=index_with_map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add that action to the UsersController, but if you are going to have more actions including Users and Maps, you might wanna think of making a new controller (to conform to the Single Responsibility Principle).

From the guides:

> If you find yourself adding many extra actions to a resourceful route,
>   it’s time to stop and ask yourself whether you’re disguising the
>   presence of another resource.

You could do this:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'index_with_map'
  end
end
```

This will enable Rails to recognize a path such as /users/index_with_map with GET.

Comment: Let's say it's just this one action for now, then.  Can I set this action up as another 'index', such that users/map calls that action?  users/map by default looks for the show action for the user 'map'?

Comment: Okay then, if you think you won't have any more actions of this sort put it in the users controller and name the action something like `index_with_map`. I am not quite sure what you mean with 'users/map calls that action`? Do you have a `map` as a model? i fill guess you don't have it..

Comment: try to give more of your code and what you have in your application so we could give you a better answer :)

Comment: Sure...  My route file looks like this:
`resources :users, :only => [:index, :index_with_map, :show, :edit, :update] do
  match '/index_with_map' => 'users#index_with_map'
end`
But hitting "users/index_with_map" results in:
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /admin/users/index_with_map
Couldn't find User with id=index_with_map`

Comment: i've edited your question with the routes and i have edited my answer.

Comment: The resource still gives me "Couldn't find User with id=index_with_map", it's clearly being routed to users#show...

Comment: SORRY SORRY, it is collection, not member

Comment: sorry for that mistake, wasn't thinking it through :)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to add new action that will deal with the users map. Then you will only need to create the corresponding view file for that action.

The users are for the same table, the functionality is only different. So why the need of different controller?

Also if you will create the another controller just for map view then there is no use of that as it's just a wastage of resources.

Another point is -

Controllers provides the user to interact with the model. So two controllers means you typically want two models. So different controllers are used when you want to do different (categories of) things.